# Return an array/map from awk to bash

Tags: arrays, bash, awk

An awk command creates an array which I want to return to bash.

```
GIT=($(history | grep -c git | awk '{ TMP[4]=$1 } END { print TMP }'))
```

and getting an error `attempt to use array TMP in a scalar context`.

So I try inside an awk use already existed array

```
GIT=()
history | grep -c git | awk 'END { GIT[4]=$1 }'
echo "${GIT[@]}" # empty result
```

but the result `GIT` arrary is empty.

The example which I presented doesn't make a lot of sense eg. why 4 in an index? It's just an example. I need use array/map created by awk where the key is an integer. And I need these original indexes, because not all keys are in sequence. I have 1,2,4,7,8 and so on.

Comment: it would help if you provided some sample input and expected output; in the meantime, for the `awk` issue ... did you mean to use field #4 as the index for the `TMP` array, eg, `TMP[$4]=$1` ? also, assuming `TMP` **is** an array, you'll need to modify the `awk/print` to cycle through the elements of the array; as for the empty `GIT` array ... the `GIT[]` array **inside** the `awk` code is only available within the `awk` code (ie, it will not be accessible by the calling/parent process)

Comment: awk isn't bash. You wouldn't expect to create an array in a C program and somehow have bash have access to that array and similarly you should have the same expectations for awk. awk and bash are 2 completely different tools with their own languages, syntax, semantics, and scopes. Right now youve posted an [XY Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/361691) - if you edit it to show us what you;re trying to **DO** instead of **HOW** you're trying to do it then we can help you do whatever it is you're trying to do the right way rather than potentially helping you implement the wrong way

Comment: glenn jackman knew what I'm trying to do. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have awk emit shell commands and then the awk output can be `source`d

```sh
GIT=()
source <(
    history |
    grep -c git |
    awk -v shellVarname="GIT" '
        {tmp[4] = $1}
        END {
            for (idx in tmp)
                printf "%s[%d]=\"%s\"\n", shellVarname, idx, tmp[idx]
        }
    '
)
declare -p GIT  # just to dump the array contents for review
```